# Adding a class to a link inside a <li> element on scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, class, addition

Is it possible to add a class to a link inside a li element when a certain part of the page is active?

I have a one page website and would like to change the color of the link when that specific part of the page is reached via scroll.

Here's my HTML:

```
<header id="header"> 
        <section class="container">
                <nav>
                    <a class="logo" href="index.html">Logo</a>
                    <div id="menu">
                        <ul id="links"> 
                            <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#clients">Clients</a></li>  
                            <li class="last"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
        </section>
    </header>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
#menu li a {
    color:#7a7a7a;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-right:20px;
}

#menu li.last a {
    color:#7a7a7a;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-right:0px;
}

#menu li.current a {
color: #0086be;
}
```

What I would like to do is to add the class .current to the link inside the li element whenever that  specific part of the page is reached.

I believe this is only possible with Javascript, can anyone point me the right path to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean to hover it when mouseOver?

Comment: U can achieve that using simple jquery. Ref http://jsfiddle.net/ggNrr/

Comment: Css does not have the ability to add or remove attributes/classes of elements.

Comment: It is unclear exactly what you are trying to do. Would you like to respond to the scroll position on the page, or the mouse position?

Comment: Basically I just want to change the color of the link when the position on the page is reached. For example; I'm scrolling through the page and as I pass through the different sections ( which have the ids #services, #about, #clients, #contact) the link color on the navigation bar changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, I guess this is what you require: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1dmzbtvs/22/). The CSS and the HTML code remains the same and this is the jQuery code which I've used:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    

var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

if (scroll > 500) {
$("#links li:first-child").addClass("current");
}

if (scroll > 750) {
$("#links li:first-child").removeClass("current");
$("#links li:nth-child(2)").addClass("current");
}

var scrollBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

if (scroll < 500) {
$("#links li:first-child").removeClass("current");
}

if (scroll < 750) {
$("#links li:nth-child(2)").removeClass("current");
}

});
```

Basically what happens is that when you scroll down to 500px, the `li:first-child` is automatically assigned the `current` class. You can modify the jQuery to suit your needs by adding more `if` queries as per your needs. You can target different `<li>`'s in your list using different child-selectors like `li:first-child`, `li:nth-child(2)` etc.

Comment: This is almost it!
The problem is that after reaching those 500px the link stays with the class .current and I would like to remove that class in order to return to the original color. 

For example between 500 and 750px I want the link to be blue (adding the .current class) but outside that reach I want it to return to gray (removing the .current class).

Comment: Please check my updated answer with the new jsFiddle link. Basically between 500px-750px, the `li:first-child` is assigned the `current` class and after 750px, when I believe your next page would begin, the `li:nth-child(2)` is given the `current` class. Similarly, when you scroll back to the top, the classes are removed when you pass their areas.

Comment: Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1dmzbtvs/24/. In this fiddle, you can see all your 4 items in the navigation menu changing colours when you scroll up or down.

Comment: Man thank you so much for your amazing effort, I really appreciate it! This works, but I think this might not be the best approach because of screen resolutions...

A user with a small screen will have to scroll much more than a user with a large screen resulting in the link change its color too early when that specific part of the page is not yet visible, and a user with a big screen will not even scroll that much until the last part of the page.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like **scrollspy** in bootstrap,
you can use it or you can find https://gist.github.com/pascaldevink/2380129 bypascaldevink

or here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ia_archiver/Kb7xq/

You will require jquery for this,

```
 $.fn.scrollspy = function ( option ) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this = $(this)
        , data = $this.data('scrollspy')
        , options = typeof option == 'object' && option
      if (!data) $this.data('scrollspy', (data = new ScrollSpy(this, options)))
      if (typeof option == 'string') data[option]()
    })
  }
  $.fn.scrollspy.Constructor = ScrollSpy
  $.fn.scrollspy.defaults = {
    offset: 10
  }
  $(function () {
    $('[data-spy="scroll"]').each(function () {
      var $spy = $(this)
      $spy.scrollspy($spy.data())
    })
  })

}(window.jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using hover function you can achieve this.i.e. on hover of specific part of the page you add the class to the link present inside the li. e.g.

```
  $('#specificPartOfPageId').hover(function(){
      $('#links').children().children('a').addClass('current');
  });
```

This would add .current class to every link present inside that UL element.
Hope this helps.

Comment: That really made sense, and I guess this is exactly what I'm trying to do, but tried it and didn't work.